# JS framework to create visual simulations on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to create some kind of simulation for example sorting algorithm on canvas. I need a JS framework which allow to transition or path transitions of some elements (i have no problem to calc coordinates), I don't want to use paperjs because I need simulation stepping (for example two elements switch) and use onFrame it's quite overhead for me, because I don't want to anything so much difficult, i need it for simple demo.

Comment: http://greensock.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at D3 (http://d3js.org/)?

Here is a blog post on using D3 with canvas http://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas/

Comment: d3 is amazing, but it's learning curve is very steep for the questioner's "simple demo".

Comment: I know d3, but @markE has right point, learning curve is not that fast, "his" library is kind a cool, I was able to create simple sorting algorithm animation in less than 20 minutes :) and that's i want :)